# Apache-PIG script: ERROR Invalid field projection on joined variable

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

The Pig script I have created works, unless I try to use `GENERATE` on the field that I joined on.

```
cc_data = LOAD 'default.complaint1' USING org.apache.hive.hcatalog.pig.HCatLoader(); 
cc2_data = LOAD 'default.complaint2' USING org.apache.hive.hcatalog.pig.HCatLoader(); 
combined = join cc_data by complaintid, cc2_data by complaintid;
```

If I do a `DESCRIBE` on my combined it shows as follows:

combined:

```
{cc_data::daterecieved: chararray,
 cc_data::product: chararray,
 cc_data::subproduct: chararray,
 cc_data::issue: chararray,
 cc_data::subissue: chararray,
 cc_data::consumercomplaintnarrative: chararray,
 cc_data::companypublicresponse: chararray,
 cc_data::company: chararray,
 cc_data::state: chararray,
 cc_data::zip: chararray,
 cc_data::submitted: chararray,
 cc_data::datesenttocompany: chararray,
 cc_data::companyresponsetoconsumer: chararray,
 cc_data::timelyresponse: chararray,
 cc_data::consumerdisputed: chararray,
 cc_data::complaintid: int,
 cc2_data::complaintid: int,
 cc2_data::complaintamount: float,
 cc2_data::consumerzip: int,
 cc2_data::creditrating: chararray,
 cc2_data::bankrupthistory: chararray}
```

I can use a `FOREACH` and `GENERATE` on all of the fields except for complaintid field. I've even tried cc_data.complaintid. I get this error:

```
ERROR 1025:
<file pig_read_orcfile.pig, line 13, column 190> Invalid field projection. Projected field [complaintid] does not exist in schema
```

Any ideas? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try

```
... FOREACH combined GENERATE cc_data::complaintid;
```

http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.9.1/basic.html#disambiguate